# Warning: mkdir(): Permission denied in /opt/lampp/htdocs/

Tags: php, ubuntu, ubuntu-16.04

I'm running on ubuntu 16.04 LTS and have installed Xampp

My code is:

```
<?php
 $dir = 'upload';
 if ( !file_exists($dir) ) {
     $oldmask = umask(0);
     mkdir ($dir, 0744);
 }
```

and I'm facing an error

> Warning: mkdir(): Permission denied in /opt/lampp/htdocs/imageupload/index1.php on line 5

What can I do?

Comment: add 755 or 777 permission to upload folder

Answer (score 13):

The problem is you do not have permission to create directory . so

try

```
sudo chmod 777 -R /opt/lampp/htdocs/
```

then run the script again . hope it'll work!

Comment: Perfect solution for me..Thank you bro.